# How to Select Multi line text as different single line texts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

> `UPDATE TBL SET  Col1='multi \r\nline \r\ntext'`

I'm using the above query to set a `col1` value to multiline value.

I wish to select `col1` as 3 rows.

I want output for

`Select col1 from tbl`

like

**COL1**

---

multi

line

text

Comment: u want to update or insert

Comment: I'm doing the both insertion and Updation and my query is how to select it in different rows

Comment: If it is insert it is possible and i can give u query for that , for update since it does on existing rows as of my knowledge it is not possible , since it has to insert extra two rows for that purpose .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To separate this string to elements we use [nodes() Method of XML data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).
To use it we should convert this string to XML format. Just replace `'\r\n'` with `'</X><X>'`:

```
WITH T AS
(
  SELECT ID,
  CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(col1,'\r\n','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmldata 
  FROM TBL
  )

SELECT T.ID,
       a.c.value('data(.)', 'VARCHAR(100)') as col1 
FROM   T
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('X') as a(c)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aaea/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Insertion

```
insert into table
Select a.na 
from table 
cross apply(Select 'multi' na union Select 'Line' union Select 'Text')a
```